# Website hosting

Tags: web-hosting, server, looking-for-hosting, webserver

First off I apologize if this is the wrong place to ask this question, if it is please direct me to the correct place. Ok with that out of the way I have a question about where to host my website. I am a fairly experienced web developer who hosts my stuff on a github.io page. This has worked for me but I want to try and get into hosting my own server  that I control. Can you Webmasters please give me an idea of what website I could use that would allow me to have a custom domain and have a server that would run basic things like php, mysql and server side scripts. I have read [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements) but it did not tell me what services would provide the best web hosting for my needs.


**Other Details:**

My site will probaly only get 10-20 visits a day so I'm not looking for heavy traffic web hosting

PHP supported needed

mysql support would be nice but, I can live without it

I would like to only be spending around $15 a month

I would need a custom domain I don't want any of that www.myname.bu1.4.com/freehosting

Comment: Please do not recreate questions when we already have 'catchall' type questions in place for this type of question. We do not want these type of questions on the site due to spam and the never amount of questions that will be asked of this nature. Questions such as these are best asked in our superb chat channel that we welcome and your get many good responses.

Answer (score 0):

[Gandi.net](http://gandi.net/hosting/) seems to have what you need for some affordable prices.

Even though I have no experience with them, they have a reputation of high quality services with members of the Debian Project (which is how I learned about them in the first place).

What I *do* know is that they are clueful and that they support Free Software project upon which they base their technology (for instance, Debian proper).